# GLSL #if directive with ==

Tags: opengl, glsl

Some people are reporting bugs in shaders in our client software. Reports looks like this:

```
ERROR: 0:63: error#71) Syntax error incorrect preprocessor directive
WARNING: 0:63: warning#64) Unexpected tokens following the preprocessor directive - expected a newline(#if )
ERROR: 0:67: error#71) Syntax error incorrect preprocessor directive
WARNING: 0:67: warning#64) Unexpected tokens following the preprocessor directive - expected a newline(#if )
ERROR: 0:71: error#71) Syntax error incorrect preprocessor directive
WARNING: 0:71: warning#64) Unexpected tokens following the preprocessor directive - expected a newline(#if )
ERROR: 0:75: error#71) Syntax error incorrect preprocessor directive
WARNING: 0:75: warning#64) Unexpected tokens following the preprocessor directive - expected a newline(#if )
```

And more. Every error is on line like this:

```
#if ATLAS_MAG_MIN_FILTER == 7 // Here goes the comment
```

We tried changing all these ifs to the following format:

```
#if (ATLAS_MAG_MIN_FILTER == 7) // Comment
```

But the error is still occurring. I cant find any documentation on the way we should write #ifs in GLSL. Can anybody tell me how to use them correctly?

Added:
ATLAS_MAG_MIN_FILTER is defined as:

```
#define ATLAS_MAG_MIN_FILTER (ATLAS_FILTER_MODE & 0x7)
```

ATLAS_FILTER_MODE is defined as:

```
#define ATLAS_FILTER_MODE 5
```

All newlines are in place.

There are errors on lines without comments too.

I uploaded full code of the shader [here](http://pastebin.com/fBsLP5xT), errors occurred on lines 63, 67, 71, 75, 79, 83, 87, 91, 111, 114, 115, 122, 125, 126.

Comment: Since the error says that it expected a newline: Is there a newline at the end of these lines?

Comment: Perhaps `ATLAS_MAG_MIN_FILTER` is defined to an empty string?

Comment: They are in big file, there clearly newlines when they should be, and loader adds newlines in the end of file automatically.

Comment: `ATLAS_MAG_MIN_FILTER` defined and is a number. Other way errors will happen for every user.

Comment: I forgot about comments, they are on this lines too. Probably, this is the problem, i will check it as soon as possible.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably it. I don't think comments are legal as part of preprocessor directives.

Comment: @reto-koradi It is not comment. There is an error where no comment on line too.

Comment: Added full code [here](http://pastebin.com/fBsLP5xT)

Comment: If it's not the comments, I'm not sure. Maybe some implementations don't like the hex format constants in the preprocessor definitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem: hex constants are not allowed in some implementations. Tested on ATI Radeon HD 4800 Series with driver version 8.17.10.1129.

I used this code as test:

```
#define TESTVAR_1 (ATLAS_MAG_MIN_FILTER & 0x7)
#define TESTVAR_2 (ATLAS_MAG_MIN_FILTER & 7)

#if (TESTVAR_1 == 0)
    void testFunc() {

    }
#endif
#if (TESTVAR_2 == 0)
    void testFunc2() {

    }
#endif
```

Error occurred only on line `#if (TESTVAR_1 == 0)` means `TESTVAR_1` is empty.

*I'm really surprised there is no error in first define itself...*

Comment: Preprocessors simply do text substitution. The expression is not evaluated when you define `TESTVAR_1`. All the preprocessor does is replace later occurrences of `TESTVAR_1` with the text on the right side of the definition.