# unexpected token after conditional expression

Tags: three.js, webgl, shader

Trying to add depth of field to my project from:
http://www.andrewberg.com/prototypes/threejs/bokeh/

But getting an error from the shader:

> three.js:16612THREE.WebGLProgram: shader error:  0 gl.VALIDATE_STATUS
>   false gl.getProgramInfoLog invalid shaders  ERROR: 0:101:
>   'DEPTH_PACKING' : unexpected token after conditional expression 
>   ERROR: 0:228: 'DEPTH_PACKING' : unexpected token after conditional
>   expression  ERROR: 0:248: 'DEPTH_PACKING' : unexpected token after
>   conditional expression  ERROR: 0:250: 'DEPTH_PACKING' : unexpected
>   token after conditional expression

And the shader which shows error:

```
HREE.WebGLShader: gl.getShaderInfoLog() fragment ERROR: 0:101: 'DEPTH_PACKING' : unexpected token after conditional expression 
ERROR: 0:228: 'DEPTH_PACKING' : unexpected token after conditional expression 
ERROR: 0:248: 'DEPTH_PACKING' : unexpected token after conditional expression 
ERROR: 0:250: 'DEPTH_PACKING' : unexpected token after conditional expression 
 1: precision highp float;
2: precision highp int;
3: #define SHADER_NAME ShaderMaterial
4: #define GAMMA_FACTOR 2
5: #define NUM_CLIPPING_PLANES 0
6: #define UNION_CLIPPING_PLANES 0
7: uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
8: uniform vec3 cameraPosition;
9: #define TONE_MAPPING
10: #define saturate(a) clamp( a, 0.0, 1.0 )
11: uniform float toneMappingExposure;
12: uniform float toneMappingWhitePoint;
13: vec3 LinearToneMapping( vec3 color ) {
14:   return toneMappingExposure * color;
15: }
16: vec3 ReinhardToneMapping( vec3 color ) {
17:   color *= toneMappingExposure;
18:   return saturate( color / ( vec3( 1.0 ) + color ) );
19: }
20: #define Uncharted2Helper( x ) max( ( ( x * ( 0.15 * x + 0.10 * 0.50 ) + 0.20 * 0.02 ) / ( x * ( 0.15 * x + 0.50 ) + 0.20 * 0.30 ) ) - 0.02 / 0.30, vec3( 0.0 ) )
21: vec3 Uncharted2ToneMapping( vec3 color ) {
22:   color *= toneMappingExposure;
23:   return saturate( Uncharted2Helper( color ) / Uncharted2Helper( vec3( toneMappingWhitePoint ) ) );
24: }
25: vec3 OptimizedCineonToneMapping( vec3 color ) {
26:   color *= toneMappingExposure;
27:   color = max( vec3( 0.0 ), color - 0.004 );
28:   return pow( ( color * ( 6.2 * color + 0.5 ) ) / ( color * ( 6.2 * color + 1.7 ) + 0.06 ), vec3( 2.2 ) );
29: }
30: 
31: vec3 toneMapping( vec3 color ) { return LinearToneMapping( color ); }
32: 
33: vec4 LinearToLinear( in vec4 value ) {
34:   return value;
35: }
36: vec4 GammaToLinear( in vec4 value, in float gammaFactor ) {
37:   return vec4( pow( value.xyz, vec3( gammaFactor ) ), value.w );
38: }
39: vec4 LinearToGamma( in vec4 value, in float gammaFactor ) {
40:   return vec4( pow( value.xyz, vec3( 1.0 / gammaFactor ) ), value.w );
41: }
42: vec4 sRGBToLinear( in vec4 value ) {
43:   return vec4( mix( pow( value.rgb * 0.9478672986 + vec3( 0.0521327014 ), vec3( 2.4 ) ), value.rgb * 0.0773993808, vec3( lessThanEqual( value.rgb, vec3( 0.04045 ) ) ) ), value.w );
44: }
45: vec4 LinearTosRGB( in vec4 value ) {
46:   return vec4( mix( pow( value.rgb, vec3( 0.41666 ) ) * 1.055 - vec3( 0.055 ), value.rgb * 12.92, vec3( lessThanEqual( value.rgb, vec3( 0.0031308 ) ) ) ), value.w );
47: }
48: vec4 RGBEToLinear( in vec4 value ) {
49:   return vec4( value.rgb * exp2( value.a * 255.0 - 128.0 ), 1.0 );
50: }
51: vec4 LinearToRGBE( in vec4 value ) {
52:   float maxComponent = max( max( value.r, value.g ), value.b );
53:   float fExp = clamp( ceil( log2( maxComponent ) ), -128.0, 127.0 );
54:   return vec4( value.rgb / exp2( fExp ), ( fExp + 128.0 ) / 255.0 );
55: }
56: vec4 RGBMToLinear( in vec4 value, in float maxRange ) {
57:   return vec4( value.xyz * value.w * maxRange, 1.0 );
58: }
59: vec4 LinearToRGBM( in vec4 value, in float maxRange ) {
60:   float maxRGB = max( value.x, max( value.g, value.b ) );
61:   float M      = clamp( maxRGB / maxRange, 0.0, 1.0 );
62:   M            = ceil( M * 255.0 ) / 255.0;
63:   return vec4( value.rgb / ( M * maxRange ), M );
64: }
65: vec4 RGBDToLinear( in vec4 value, in float maxRange ) {
66:     return vec4( value.rgb * ( ( maxRange / 255.0 ) / value.a ), 1.0 );
67: }
68: vec4 LinearToRGBD( in vec4 value, in float maxRange ) {
69:     float maxRGB = max( value.x, max( value.g, value.b ) );
70:     float D      = max( maxRange / maxRGB, 1.0 );
71:     D            = min( floor( D ) / 255.0, 1.0 );
72:     return vec4( value.rgb * ( D * ( 255.0 / maxRange ) ), D );
73: }
74: const mat3 cLogLuvM = mat3( 0.2209, 0.3390, 0.4184, 0.1138, 0.6780, 0.7319, 0.0102, 0.1130, 0.2969 );
75: vec4 LinearToLogLuv( in vec4 value )  {
76:   vec3 Xp_Y_XYZp = value.rgb * cLogLuvM;
77:   Xp_Y_XYZp = max(Xp_Y_XYZp, vec3(1e-6, 1e-6, 1e-6));
78:   vec4 vResult;
79:   vResult.xy = Xp_Y_XYZp.xy / Xp_Y_XYZp.z;
80:   float Le = 2.0 * log2(Xp_Y_XYZp.y) + 127.0;
81:   vResult.w = fract(Le);
82:   vResult.z = (Le - (floor(vResult.w*255.0))/255.0)/255.0;
83:   return vResult;
84: }
85: const mat3 cLogLuvInverseM = mat3( 6.0014, -2.7008, -1.7996, -1.3320, 3.1029, -5.7721, 0.3008, -1.0882, 5.6268 );
86: vec4 LogLuvToLinear( in vec4 value ) {
87:   float Le = value.z * 255.0 + value.w;
88:   vec3 Xp_Y_XYZp;
89:   Xp_Y_XYZp.y = exp2((Le - 127.0) / 2.0);
90:   Xp_Y_XYZp.z = Xp_Y_XYZp.y / value.y;
91:   Xp_Y_XYZp.x = value.x * Xp_Y_XYZp.z;
92:   vec3 vRGB = Xp_Y_XYZp.rgb * cLogLuvInverseM;
93:   return vec4( max(vRGB, 0.0), 1.0 );
94: }
95: 
96: vec4 mapTexelToLinear( vec4 value ) { return LinearToLinear( value ); }
97: vec4 envMapTexelToLinear( vec4 value ) { return LinearToLinear( value ); }
98: vec4 emissiveMapTexelToLinear( vec4 value ) { return LinearToLinear( value ); }
99: vec4 linearToOutputTexel( vec4 value ) { return LinearToLinear( value ); }
100: 
101: #if DEPTH_PACKING == 3200
102:    uniform float opacity;
103: #endif
104: #define PI 3.14159265359
105: #define PI2 6.28318530718
106: #define RECIPROCAL_PI 0.31830988618
107: #define RECIPROCAL_PI2 0.15915494
108: #define LOG2 1.442695
109: #define EPSILON 1e-6
110: #define saturate(a) clamp( a, 0.0, 1.0 )
111: #define whiteCompliment(a) ( 1.0 - saturate( a ) )
112: float pow2( const in float x ) { return x*x; }
113: float pow3( const in float x ) { return x*x*x; }
114: float pow4( const in float x ) { float x2 = x*x; return x2*x2; }
115: float average( const in vec3 color ) { return dot( color, vec3( 0.3333 ) ); }
116: highp float rand( const in vec2 uv ) {
117:    const highp float a = 12.9898, b = 78.233, c = 43758.5453;
118:    highp float dt = dot( uv.xy, vec2( a,b ) ), sn = mod( dt, PI );
119:    return fract(sin(sn) * c);
120: }
121: struct IncidentLight {
122:    vec3 color;
123:    vec3 direction;
124:    bool visible;
125: };
126: struct ReflectedLight {
127:    vec3 directDiffuse;
128:    vec3 directSpecular;
129:    vec3 indirectDiffuse;
130:    vec3 indirectSpecular;
131: };
132: struct GeometricContext {
133:    vec3 position;
134:    vec3 normal;
135:    vec3 viewDir;
136: };
137: vec3 transformDirection( in vec3 dir, in mat4 matrix ) {
138:    return normalize( ( matrix * vec4( dir, 0.0 ) ).xyz );
139: }
140: vec3 inverseTransformDirection( in vec3 dir, in mat4 matrix ) {
141:    return normalize( ( vec4( dir, 0.0 ) * matrix ).xyz );
142: }
143: vec3 projectOnPlane(in vec3 point, in vec3 pointOnPlane, in vec3 planeNormal ) {
144:    float distance = dot( planeNormal, point - pointOnPlane );
145:    return - distance * planeNormal + point;
146: }
147: float sideOfPlane( in vec3 point, in vec3 pointOnPlane, in vec3 planeNormal ) {
148:    return sign( dot( point - pointOnPlane, planeNormal ) );
149: }
150: vec3 linePlaneIntersect( in vec3 pointOnLine, in vec3 lineDirection, in vec3 pointOnPlane, in vec3 planeNormal ) {
151:    return lineDirection * ( dot( planeNormal, pointOnPlane - pointOnLine ) / dot( planeNormal, lineDirection ) ) + pointOnLine;
152: }
153: 
154: vec3 packNormalToRGB( const in vec3 normal ) {
155:   return normalize( normal ) * 0.5 + 0.5;
156: }
157: vec3 unpackRGBToNormal( const in vec3 rgb ) {
158:   return 1.0 - 2.0 * rgb.xyz;
159: }
160: const float PackUpscale = 256. / 255.;const float UnpackDownscale = 255. / 256.;
161: const vec3 PackFactors = vec3( 256. * 256. * 256., 256. * 256.,  256. );
162: const vec4 UnpackFactors = UnpackDownscale / vec4( PackFactors, 1. );
163: const float ShiftRight8 = 1. / 256.;
164: vec4 packDepthToRGBA( const in float v ) {
165:    vec4 r = vec4( fract( v * PackFactors ), v );
166:    r.yzw -= r.xyz * ShiftRight8;   return r * PackUpscale;
167: }
168: float unpackRGBAToDepth( const in vec4 v ) {
169:    return dot( v, UnpackFactors );
170: }
171: float viewZToOrthographicDepth( const in float viewZ, const in float near, const in float far ) {
172:   return ( viewZ + near ) / ( near - far );
173: }
174: float orthographicDepthToViewZ( const in float linearClipZ, const in float near, const in float far ) {
175:   return linearClipZ * ( near - far ) - near;
176: }
177: float viewZToPerspectiveDepth( const in float viewZ, const in float near, const in float far ) {
178:   return (( near + viewZ ) * far ) / (( far - near ) * viewZ );
179: }
180: float perspectiveDepthToViewZ( const in float invClipZ, const in float near, const in float far ) {
181:   return ( near * far ) / ( ( far - near ) * invClipZ - far );
182: }
183: 
184: #if defined( USE_MAP ) || defined( USE_BUMPMAP ) || defined( USE_NORMALMAP ) || defined( USE_SPECULARMAP ) || defined( USE_ALPHAMAP ) || defined( USE_EMISSIVEMAP ) || defined( USE_ROUGHNESSMAP ) || defined( USE_METALNESSMAP )
185:    varying vec2 vUv;
186: #endif
187: #ifdef USE_MAP
188:    uniform sampler2D map;
189: #endif
190: 
191: #ifdef USE_ALPHAMAP
192:    uniform sampler2D alphaMap;
193: #endif
194: 
195: #ifdef USE_LOGDEPTHBUF
196:    uniform float logDepthBufFC;
197:    #ifdef USE_LOGDEPTHBUF_EXT
198:        varying float vFragDepth;
199:    #endif
200: #endif
201: 
202: #if NUM_CLIPPING_PLANES > 0
203:    #if ! defined( PHYSICAL ) && ! defined( PHONG )
204:        varying vec3 vViewPosition;
205:    #endif
206:    uniform vec4 clippingPlanes[ NUM_CLIPPING_PLANES ];
207: #endif
208: 
209: void main() {
210:    #if NUM_CLIPPING_PLANES > 0
211:    for ( int i = 0; i < UNION_CLIPPING_PLANES; ++ i ) {
212:        vec4 plane = clippingPlanes[ i ];
213:        if ( dot( vViewPosition, plane.xyz ) > plane.w ) discard;
214:    }
215:        
216:    #if UNION_CLIPPING_PLANES < NUM_CLIPPING_PLANES
217:        bool clipped = true;
218:        for ( int i = UNION_CLIPPING_PLANES; i < NUM_CLIPPING_PLANES; ++ i ) {
219:            vec4 plane = clippingPlanes[ i ];
220:            clipped = ( dot( vViewPosition, plane.xyz ) > plane.w ) && clipped;
221:        }
222:        if ( clipped ) discard;
223:    
224:    #endif
225: #endif
226: 
227:    vec4 diffuseColor = vec4( 1.0 );
228:    #if DEPTH_PACKING == 3200
229:        diffuseColor.a = opacity;
230:    #endif
231:    #ifdef USE_MAP
232:    vec4 texelColor = texture2D( map, vUv );
233:    texelColor = mapTexelToLinear( texelColor );
234:    diffuseColor *= texelColor;
235: #endif
236: 
237:    #ifdef USE_ALPHAMAP
238:    diffuseColor.a *= texture2D( alphaMap, vUv ).g;
239: #endif
240: 
241:    #ifdef ALPHATEST
242:    if ( diffuseColor.a < ALPHATEST ) discard;
243: #endif
244: 
245:    #if defined(USE_LOGDEPTHBUF) && defined(USE_LOGDEPTHBUF_EXT)
246:    gl_FragDepthEXT = log2(vFragDepth) * logDepthBufFC * 0.5;
247: #endif
248:    #if DEPTH_PACKING == 3200
249:        gl_FragColor = vec4( vec3( gl_FragCoord.z ), opacity );
250:    #elif DEPTH_PACKING == 3201
251:        gl_FragColor = packDepthToRGBA( gl_FragCoord.z );
252:    #endif
253: }
254:
```

Comment: Maybe this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26244930/glsl-if-directive-with) will help. Where and how do you define `DEPTH_PACKING`?

Answer (score 0):

`DEPTH_PACKING` seems to be not defined.

I think the `depth shader` is used by another parent shader and it is why it get and error when we want to use him alone.

I resolve the problem by rewriting and removing all `DEPTH_PACKING` conditions :

Exemple with the `depth_frag.glsl`:

```
#include <common>
#include <packing>
#include <uv_pars_fragment>
#include <map_pars_fragment>
#include <alphamap_pars_fragment>
#include <logdepthbuf_pars_fragment>
#include <clipping_planes_pars_fragment>

void main() {
    #include <clipping_planes_fragment>

    vec4 diffuseColor = vec4( 1.0 );

    #include <map_fragment>
    #include <alphamap_fragment>
    #include <alphatest_fragment>

    #include <logdepthbuf_fragment>

    gl_FragColor = packDepthToRGBA( gl_FragCoord.z );
}
```

You can find the base of this shader here: [/r86/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderLib/depth_frag.glsl](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/r86/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderLib/depth_frag.glsl).